# run function if form fields are not null

Tags: php

Is it alright to post the isset password like this?

I think it should be `if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset(md5($_POST['password'])))` - since it posts it encrypted, but if I wrap md5 around the password w/i the conditional, it does not work properly.

```
if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {
 //run authentication
} else {
 //show form
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brad, yes it's ok. There is really no benefit to posting the password **hashed** (not encrypted). First, you have to use javascript to do that, and it's easily circumvented. Hashing of the submitted password should be done server side to compare with the stored hashed value.

**Edit**:

Plus, run the following and see what you get:

```
<?php echo md5(NULL);
```

Thus, md5 *always* returns a value.

On top of that try running the following:

```
<?php var_dump(isset(md5($_POST['password'])));
```

You'll see the following: `Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context`

[isset()](http://php.net/isset) can only be used with a variable.

**Edit:**

There is a difference between [hashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) and [encryption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encryption). MD5 is a simple hash, one that isn't even cryptographically secure.

Yes, you should not submit passwords in plaintext to your server, but hashing them client side is the *same thing*. You should be using [HTTPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Secure) for password form submissions, this is how you *encrypt* communications between your server and the client.

Comment: I was just worried that it is bad to post a password un-encrypted, even in a conditional.

Comment: If you want password security use SSL. Besides that, there is nothing more you can really do that can't be circumvented.

Comment: Brad: You are not understanding what encrypted is. md5() is _not_ encryption it is hashing.

Comment: Also, your PHP code has nothing to do with how the data is submitted. By the time that conditional is executed the password is already submitted in whatever form it came from the client in. You can change your PHP as much as you want, it doesn't affect the data that gets POSTed.

Comment: it is alright to do isset($_POST['password']) w/i the conditional? Just making sure. :)

Answer (score 1):

The whole purpose of

```
if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {
```

is to check if both POST parameters are set/available. There's no authentication involved, not even an assumption about the type of both elements (could be strings, arrays, ...). Only "is there such parameter in the request" and "can I access this element without raising a notice: undefined index".

No let's compare that to `isset(md5($_POST['password']))`
md5() takes a string, so md5($_POST['password']) makes two assumptions.
a) There is an element $_POST['password'], the very thing the "original" test checks.
b) (string)$_POST['password'] makes any sense, since whatever you pass to md5() is cast to string. If you pass an array the result is the same as for md5('Array');
Plus md5() always returns a string (the string representation of the hash for the input), so isset() is always true and doesn't make much sense there. (edit: *would be* always true, if isset() *could be* used with the return value of a function. But it can't, see comments)

bottom line; The "original" version serves a "well defined" purpose, the isset(md5(..)) version not so much ;-)

Comment: It's simpler even. isset() can't take a function as input, and md5() will hash anything, even NULL.

Comment: You're right, isset(fn()) causes a "Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context". Ok, then it not only makes no sense in a logical way, it's impossible in practice =] And md5(null)===md5('') since (string)null===''

Answer (score -2):

If the fields are in a form which is submitted, then those values will *always* be `isset`. What you probably want to check is whether or not they are empty. One simple way is to compare to an empty string, but that requires that you first check that the variable is set, otherwise, when the form hasn't been submitted, you'll get an "array key does not exist" warning. Thankfully, there's a handy method called [`empty()`](http://php.net/empty) which checks whether a given variable has been set *and* whether it has a non-falsey value -- hence you usually want to check if something is *not* empty.

```
$x = "";
!empty($x);  // false
isset($x);   // true :(

// beware though:
$x = "0";
!empty($x);  // false
```

Think of it as a shorthand for this:

```
isset($x) && $x != false
```

Comment: -1: This doesn't really address any of the several fundamental misunderstandings the OP makes. Specifically, the OP doesn't show clear understanding of how form submission works, hashing, or encryption. What does empty() have to do with anything?

Comment: @hobodave Well it looked as though he was trying to tell whether there were values in the fields.